# Get latest value by date

Tags: powershell, sorting, import-csv

I have csv sorted by date like:

```
15.02.2019;pc1;5;
15.02.2019;pc2;0;
16.02.2019;pc3;2;
16.02.2019;pc1;0;
17.02.2019;pc2;2;
18.02.2019;pc1;0;
18.02.2019;pc1;1;
18.02.2019;pc2;1;
```

I wanna get latest by date PC with value. Must be like this:

```
pc2;1
pc1;1
pc3;2
```

My code:

```
$info=Import-Csv 'my_file.txt' -Header date,pc,value -Delimiter ';'
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$datas=$info | Where-Object {($_."date" -as [DateTime]) -gt $deadline} | Sort-Object {$_."date" -as [DateTime]} -Descending| Sort-Object -property pc -unique
```

and output is:

```
date       pc  value
----       --  -----
18.02.2019 pc1 0    
18.02.2019 pc2 1    
16.02.2019 pc3 2
```

How I can get first newest PC wit value?

Comment: `$datas | Select -first 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to do what you appear to want. [*grin*]

the only things a tad odd are ...

- the "fake reading in a CSV file"
  that is just to get the sample data in without needed to create a file.
- using `Group-Object` to cluster the items by the `.PC` property value

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
15.02.2019;pc1;5;
15.02.2019;pc2;0;
16.02.2019;pc3;2;
16.02.2019;pc1;0;
17.02.2019;pc2;2;
18.02.2019;pc1;0;
18.02.2019;pc1;1;
18.02.2019;pc2;1;
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header Date, PC, Value

$EU_DatePattern = 'dd.MM.yyyy'
$Deadline = [datetime]::Now.Date.AddDays(-30)

$Results = $InStuff |
    ForEach-Object {
        # my date format is yyyy-MM-dd, so the "-as [datetime]" fails
        $_.Date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, $EU_DatePattern, $Null)
        $_
        } |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Date -gt $Deadline
        } |
    Sort-Object -Property Date, Value |
    Group-Object -Property PC |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            PC = $_.Name
            # the very last item in the ".Group" array will be
            #    - the newest
            #    - have the highest ".Value"
            Value = $_.Group[-1].Value
            }
        }

$Results
```

output ...

```
PC  Value
--  -----
pc2 1    
pc1 1    
pc3 2
```

personally, i would seriously consider keeping the date to go with each item.

Comment: @Damir - you are most welcome! glad to have helped some ... [*grin*]